The android room PageSource<Key, Value> is not loading any thing
I'm trying to get information from my database using Paging3 package which is in jetpack libraries and I could not make it work for some reason its not working at all no error is thrown and I did everything manually too can any one help me fix the problem ?
My room Dao is
@Dao
interface ContactDao {
    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg contacts: Contact)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE id=:id")
    fun getById(id: Int): Contact?

    @Query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE number=:number")
    fun getByNumber(number: String): Contact?

    @Query(
        """
SELECT 
    contact.id,
    contact.name,
    contact.number,
    MAX(contact_message.message_time) AS latest_message_time,
    COUNT(contact_message.id) as messages_count,
    contact_message.message_body as latest_message_body
FROM
    contact
INNER JOIN
    contact_message
ON
    contact_message.contact_id = contact.id
GROUP BY
    contact.id
ORDER BY
    latest_message_time DESC;
    """
    )
    fun getAll(): List<ContactWithCount>

    @Query(
        """
SELECT 
    contact.id,
    contact.name,
    contact.number,
    MAX(contact_message.message_time) AS latest_message_time,
    COUNT(contact_message.id) as messages_count,
    contact_message.message_body as latest_message_body
FROM
    contact
INNER JOIN
    contact_message
ON
    contact_message.contact_id = contact.id
GROUP BY
    contact.id
ORDER BY
    latest_message_time DESC;
    """
    )
    fun getAllWithPagination(): PagingSource<Int, ContactWithCount>
}

and the ViewModel function is
class SomeClass {
    @ExperimentalPagingApi
    fun getAllContactsPager(): Flow<PagingData<ContactWithCount>> {
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 20),
        ) {
            db.contactDao().getAllWithPagination()
        }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    }
}

and my ui compose code is
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
@Composable
fun ContactsList(vm: SmsViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val pager = vm.getAllContactsPager().collectAsLazyPagingItems()
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        items(
            count = pager.itemCount
        ) { index ->
            val item = pager[index]
            item?.let {
                ContactBasicInfoCard(vm = vm, contactWithCount = item)
            }
        }
    }
}

for some reason its not loading any data
I tried to do every thing manually and it did not work at all

You need to keep the Flow as a val in your ViewModel instead of creating a new one with each call to you get method

It sims like I could simply fix the problem by removing the ; semicolon from @Query
@Dao
interface ContactDao {
    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg contacts: Contact)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE id=:id")
    fun getById(id: Int): Contact?

    @Query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE number=:number")
    fun getByNumber(number: String): Contact?

    @Query(
        """
SELECT 
    contact.id,
    contact.name,
    contact.number,
    MAX(contact_message.message_time) AS latest_message_time,
    COUNT(contact_message.id) as messages_count,
    contact_message.message_body as latest_message_body
FROM
    contact
INNER JOIN
    contact_message
ON
    contact_message.contact_id = contact.id
GROUP BY
    contact.id
ORDER BY
    latest_message_time DESC
    """
    )
    fun getAll(): List<ContactWithCount>

    @Query(
        """
SELECT 
    contact.id,
    contact.name,
    contact.number,
    MAX(contact_message.message_time) AS latest_message_time,
    COUNT(contact_message.id) as messages_count,
    contact_message.message_body as latest_message_body
FROM
    contact
INNER JOIN
    contact_message
ON
    contact_message.contact_id = contact.id
GROUP BY
    contact.id
ORDER BY
    latest_message_time DESC
    """
    )
    fun getAllWithPagination(): PagingSource<Int, ContactWithCount>
}

